# The same slug in multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, slug

We have a project that uses several custom taxonomies, and we're finding that the client wants to add the same term in several of them. While the first slug for Foo may be `foo`, subsequent copies of Foo in different taxonomies become `foo-2`.

It would be nicer if the two terms could both use the same slug. It would be less confusing, and allow for nicer URLs like `search?tax=foo` rather than `search?tax=foo-2`.

I notice that the `wp_terms` and `wp_term_taxonomy` table are separate, leading me to believe that it's technically possible for the same term (Foo with the slug `foo`) to appear in more than one taxonomy. But this option isn't exposed in the user interface. Is there a good reason for this? Would I be risking future brokenness by fiddling with the database like that?

Comment: A possible related problem: See this
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28799/problems-editing-removing-a-term-thats-in-multiple-taxonomies

Answer (score 1):

When you say *keyword*, do you mean *term*?

I just did a quick test to confirm: I can have the same *term*, which has the same *slug*, in both the *Category* and *Post Tag* taxonomies, so I assume that custom taxonomies likewise can have terms with the same slug.

So, might there be some taxonomy/term confusion happening here? The `search?tax=foo` *seems* to imply a search based on a *taxonomy*, rather than on a *taxonomy term*. A *taxonomy term* search would look like `search?taxonomy=foo&term=bar`, or perhaps `search?term=bar`.

Comment: Yes, I meant 'term' throughout. I didn't mean `taxonomy=foo&term=bar`, I meant `my-taxonomy=foo`.

Comment: I'm still confused. What is `my-taxonomy=foo`?

Comment: `my-taxonomy` is one of several custom taxonomies. `foo` is the slug of a term in that taxonomy. From my own tests, Wordpress doesn't accept the same slug to be used in multiple taxonomies, complaining that "The slug “foo” is already in use by another term "

Comment: I clearly didn't describe my question very well. I'll have a think about how better to rephrase it.

Comment: **I know this is an old post, but...** I see that it's not possible to have the same term (with the same slug) under a category and tag (or between any taxonomies). Was this change made in WordPress since you posted your answer? I asked a similar question today: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/120096/10691