# How to edit/remove a term that's in multiple taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, slug

Some of the terms on my site appear with the same exact slug, in multiple taxonomies.

For example: 'education' appears in both the 'department' taxonomy and the 'topic' taxonomy.

Now, I can't seem to modify or delete a term from one taxonomy without affecting the term in the other taxonomy.

- If I change 'education' to 'department-of-education' in the
  'department' taxonomy, it changes to 'department-of-education' in the
  'topic' taxonomy as well.
- If I delete 'education' from departments,
  it disappears from topics as well.

How can I separate the terms?

Wordpress does seem to prevent same-named terms in different taxonomies in the admin, but my taxonomies and terms were imported in the course of a site migration using a WXR file, and Wordpress let them in—so now I'm stuck with them.

Comment: Do both terms have the same ID ?

Comment: Yes, they do. So the edit and delete links read, e.g., 

?...taxonomy=department&tag_ID=82 and 

?...taxonomy=topic&tag_ID=82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, though terms could not be *edited* without affecting all instances, they *could* be deleted without deleting all instances.

So, it looks as though the answer is this:

- you ***cannot*** separately edit a term that's in multiple taxonomies, but
- you ***can*** remove that term from a taxonomy without removing it from the
  other taxonomies it appears in.

For related ideas, see http://www.wpquestions.com/question/show/id/3005.